# How can I reuse object variable with GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to reuse variable `borderSwitches` but the only way to achieve this is to re-initialise it in the latter `if` clause, is there a more elegant way of achieving this?

```
borderTable := &databasemodel.borderTable{}
err = tx.First(borderSwitches, &databasemodel.borderTable{BaseModel: databasemodel.BaseModel{UUID: lagPair.borderTable}})
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Errorf("Fetching border switch by UUID: %v", err)
}

if !borderTable.FirstBorderSwitchID.Valid {
    borderTableFirstID := borderSwitches.ID
    borderTable = &databasemodel.borderTable{}
    err = tx.First(borderSwitches, &databasemodel.borderTable{FirstBorderTableID: sql.NullInt64{Int64: borderTableFirstID, Valid: true}})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Errorf("Fetching border table by DB ID: %v", err)
    }
}

fmt.Println("borderTable: %v\n", borderTable)
```

Comment: You are initializing, but not using the variable `borderTable`

Comment: Well that is pretty much irrelevant, it’s about why I have to re-initialise the variable

Comment: I dont get what the problem here.

Comment: The problem is rather ugly syntax, that I have to re-declare variable `borderTable = &databasemodel.borderTable{}`

Comment: You don't even use the variable. Is this really the code you're running? Since you're not using it at all, it is hard to say if there's a better way.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I've fixed that, now I'm using the variable :)

Comment: If you need to reinitialize the variable, then what you're doing it right. And, no, you're not using the variable, you're initializing it twice and printing it.

Comment: So this is a Gorm thing, that the reinitializing of the variable is needed?

Comment: you want to reuse `borderSwitches` or  `borderTable ` ?

Comment: @AbinashGhosh `borderTable`, just puzzled by the two time initialisation, first at the top, second inside the `if` sentence

Comment: @JonB Okay, but you wrote `I'm trying to reuse variable borderSwitches` and use don't use `borderTable` anywhere after initialize it.